# How to average every 12 columns for each row in r

Tags: r, matrix, mean

I have a matrix which contains 100 rows and 120 columns, I wonder how I can find the mean value for every 12 columns for each row. so I can have the annual mean. Thanks.

```
set.seed(1234)
data=rnorm(100*120)
data=matrix(data,nrow = 100,ncol = 120)
```

Comment: Perhaps `sapply(split.default(as.data.frame(data), ((1:120)-1)%/%12 + 1), rowMeans)`

Comment: @akrun You are amazing. Could you explain your code a bit? Thanks.

Comment: Grouped operations in R make more sense by rows, not cols. There's a dedicated function, `rowsum` for the former case. Here, it's `t(rowsum(t(data), gl(10,12)))/12` (borrowing from Gabor's answer).

Comment: `((1:120)-1)%/%12 + 1` and `gl(10, 12)` give similar results.  The former gives a numeric vector while the latter gives a factor and avoids the complex formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row `r`, apply `tapply(r, gl(10, 12), mean)` to it:

```
t(apply(data, 1, tapply, gl(10, 12), mean))
```

> Note that the above does not use any properties of `mean` so it
>   generalizes to other aggregate functions by replacing `mean` with some
>   other function.

Another possibility which also generalizes is to reshape the matrix into a 3d array and apply the mean over the indicated dimensions:

```
apply(array(data, c(100, 12, 10)), c(1, 3), mean)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. @akrun also suggests a solution and he uses %/%, I wonder if you know about this operator. Thanks.

Comment: @YangYang: "_%/% indicates integer division_". See `help("%/%")`.

Comment: `((1:120)-1)%/%12 + 1` and `gl(10, 12)` give similar results.  The former gives a numeric vector while the latter gives a factor and avoids the complex formula.

Comment: @UweBlock Thanks a lot.